# Read XML to a list<string[]> using xmlread

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I am going to read an xml file of a gps points to a list and later convert them to a polygon and save in database.
Here is my problem..When I try to read file every item in list is the same as others..can you help me with my problem?thanks in advanced
here is my code:

```
  public List<string[]> loadXML(string xmlpath)
    {

        List<string[]> points = new List<string[]>();

        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlpath);
        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            string[] item = new string[3];
            if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "trkpt"))
            {
                if (xmlReader.HasAttributes) 
                {

                    item[0] = xmlReader.GetAttribute("lat");
                    item[1] = xmlReader.GetAttribute("lon");

                }


            }
            if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "ele"))
            {


                    item[2] = xmlReader.ReadInnerXml();


            }
            points.Add(item);

        }
        return points;
    }
```

and here is a peice of my xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gpx xmlns="" xmlns:gpxx="" xmlns:wptx1="" xmlns:gpxtpx="" creator="GPSMAP 78s" version="1.1" xmlns:xsi="" xsi:schemaLocation="">
<metadata>
<link href=""><text>Garmin International</text></link>
<time>2014-06-18T13:55:07Z</time></metadata>
<trk><name>PV164B2KHE</name>
<extensions><gpxx:TrackExtension><gpxx:DisplayColor>Cyan</gpxx:DisplayColor></gpxx:TrackExtension></extensions>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="31.0403929744" lon="51.5264290944"><ele>2089.08</ele><time>2014-06-18T13:45:57Z</time></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="31.0403881129" lon="51.5264252387"><ele>2088.60</ele><time>2014-06-18T13:46:01Z</time></trkpt></trkseg></trk></gpx>
```

I want to extract lat,lon and ele for each point

Comment: Save yourself some grief, and use XDocument.Load(xmlpath). Than you can use System.Xml.Linq to query and retrieve elements you need.

Comment: @Darek as I have read before xDocument method consumes more memory  than xml read..What do you think about it?There is not any sugestions why it happens to my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Linq to XML for that:

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("path");

XNamepsace ns = xmlDocument.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var values = xmlDocument.Root
             .Descendants(ns + "trkpt")
             .Select(x => new
                    {
                        lat = (string)x.Attribute("lat"), 
                        lon = (string)x.Attribute("lon"), 
                        ele = (string)x.Element(ns + "ele")
                    });
```

Your mistake is `xmlReader.Read()` reads the next node, but you are creating a `string[]` array for each node.A node can not be a `trkpt` and `ele` at the same time. So that will never give you the desired result.

Comment: @user3818085 try adding ToList() after the Select

Comment: I have tested your new edit and I got an error here     'XNamepsace ns = xmlDocument.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();' it says it can not convert type System.Xml.Linq.xnamespsace

Comment: It cant find any definition for it..Is there any using that I have to add?or mis spell or sth like that?I think the right spell is `XNamespace ` I'll test that and let you know the results

Comment: @MajidHojati add namespace to ele as well `ele = (string)x.Element(ns + "ele")`

Comment: I found the solution..I  used  `ele = (string)x.Elements().First()` and It works fine..what if I want to extract <name>name</name> from xml?Do I must write a new query?